# How can I control audio autoplay in Javascript without using <iframe>?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to play background music with audio tag and javascript. music[0].play() works well in button click and window click functions but music[0].autoplay=true and music[0].play() both don't work in window.onload and body.onload. How can I make it run?

main.html

```
<body onload="musicOn()">
  <div>
    <audio class="music">
      <source src="./media/newuser.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
  </div>
</body>
```

main.js

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var btn = document.getElementById("title_btn");
var music = document.getElementsByClassName("music");
var video = document.getElementsByClassName("videopop");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

window.onload = function() {
  music[0].play();
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    video[0].play();
    music[0].pause();
  };

  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    video[0].pause();
    video[0].currentTime = 0;
    music[0].play();
  };

  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
      video[0].pause();
      video[0].currentTime = 0;
      music[0].play();
    }
  };
};
```

Comment: Can you put your code in a codepen or jsfiddle and provide the link?

Comment: here! >> https://codepen.io/DODAM_KWON/pen/wRYeQz

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Autoplay is no longer effective, unless the user has interacted with the site.

Some older, but relevant info here:  https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: Aren't there any way to control it in javascript too?

Comment: @H.Kwon No, there isn't.  Due to developers abusing this for years, we all now have to live with this policy.